# bootstrap collapsing navbar shows extra animation when collapse with js

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

When using bootstraps default navbar: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar, the menu will not collapse automatically, when selecting a menu item.

I want to change this behaviour with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var activatableButtons = $('.nav.navbar-nav a'),
        navbar = $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1');

    activatableButtons.click(function(){
        navbar.collapse('hide');
    });

});
```

I am using:

1. jquery 2.1.0
2. bootstrap 3.2.0
3. HTML: Default Navbar example http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

I set up a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ludmilla/5c3supgt/

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION: animations seen when selecting a menu button.

seemingly the collapse state of the menu is toggled, when clicking the first and second time.
After the two initial clicks everything works as expected - no more animations.

Q: how to set things up, so that the state after 2 clicks is present right at the start?

TEST 1:

- make browser wide, so that menu is in 'desktop mode'
- Run code
- click on one of the 'Link' buttons
  -> ERROR: some animation is seen
- click on one of the 'Link' buttons
  -> ERROR: some animation is seen
- click on one of the 'Link' buttons
  -> OK: no animation

no more animations - OK

TEST 2:

- make browser wide, so that menu is in 'desktop mode'
- Run code
- click on one of the 'Link' buttons
  -> ERROR: some animation is seen
- make browser narrow, so that menu is in 'phone mode'
  -> ERROR: menu is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple: just one extra line needed, to get things initialized properly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var activatableButtons = $('.nav.navbar-nav a'),
        navbar = $('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1');

    // this extra line fixes the problem:
    navbar.collapse({toggle: false});

    activatableButtons.click(function(){
        navbar.collapse('hide');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You posted some code that you have added which was meant to add a function to menu items. Realize trhat you only want this code to affect their function if they are being displayed in the collapsed version of your menu, not when the screen is wide enough to display without collapsed version of menu.

You just need to define activatableButtons more specifically.

Rather than

```
 var activatableButtons = $('.nav.navbar-nav a'),
```

you might use

```
 var activatableButtons = $('.nav.navbar-collapse.collapse.in li a'),
```

That might not be exactly what you need but I hope it shows you at least what you're not understanding. What i can say definitively is that I used this code just now to resolve a similar dilemma on a project of mine:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $(".navbar.navbar-collapse.collapse.in li a").click(function(event) {
              $(".navbar-collapse").collapse('hide');
          });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: sorry to be that late. I've checked your fix and do not understand it. Since the jquery select only finds 'a' elements, which are inside a navbar with class 'in' set, the selection is empty ('in' is not set at start) and the click callback is never reached. You can check this: 1. change the fiddle code, 2. run, 3. narrow the view, 4. open the menu, 5. select a link. I want the menu to close with this selection, but this will not happen. This is working with the original selector - with the mentioned side effect. Meanwhile I found a one line solution; see my answer.